# Spark MLib Statistics: where is it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I try to:

```
 import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.MultivariateStatisticalSummary
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
 import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
```

I get an error:

```
 object Statistics is not a member of package org.apache.spark.mllib.stat
```

How to fix this?

**Update**

I use Spark 1.1.0 and submit job as:

```
/home/zork/usr/spark-1.1.0/bin/spark-submit \
  --class Data \
  --master local[*] \
  --driver-memory 2g \
    /home/zork/wks/ShopList/target/scala-2.10/shoplist_2.10-1.0.jar \
    /home/zork/wks/ShopList/data/orders-4.csv \
    /home/zork/wks/ShopList/data/books.csv \
    /home/zork/wks/ShopList/data/erros.csv
```

Any ideas?

And my build.sbt:

```
$ cat build.sbt
name := "ShopList"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.0.0" % "provided"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `spark-mllib` sbt dependency to 1.1.0 or a newer version. `Statistics` is not available in 1.0.0:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.1.0" % "provided"
```

Answer (score 1):

what is your spark version ?

Are you using this on spark shell or using spark submit job.

i am using this with spark 1.2 and having no issues

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.2.0"

Comment: using sbt ?  please send me the dependency you are using for your project

Comment: also edi is right. try my dependency in your spark sbt. I can run the program without issues in that case

Comment: Thanks, updating spark-mllib sbt dependency to 1.1.0 solved this!